# How to Quantise an indicator in MQL4?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I am failing over and over trying to get this indicator to run quantised with 2 buffers in [mql4](/questions/tagged/mql4). After a long time reading I have put 2 extra buffers in to squish it :/ because:

> the indicator is sitting between **0.1430-0.1427** at present but **doesn't have a fixed top and bottom**.

I can't seem to suss it; cool indicator but won't play fair!

```c
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers   4
#property indicator_color1    Lime
#property indicator_color2    Red
#property indicator_color3    CLR_NONE
#property indicator_color4    CLR_NONE
//#property indicator_minimum 0
//#property indicator_maximum 100
extern int    P   =   13;
extern int    T   = 3000;
extern double P2  =    0.001;
//int         MIN =    0;
//int         MAX =  100;
double G[];
double R[];
double B3[];
double B4[];

int init(){
   IndicatorBuffers(4);
   SetIndexBuffer( 0, G  );SetIndexStyle( 0, DRAW_LINE, STYLE_SOLID, 1, Lime );
   SetIndexBuffer( 1, R  );SetIndexStyle( 1, DRAW_LINE, STYLE_SOLID, 1, Red  );
   SetIndexBuffer( 2, B3 );SetIndexStyle( 2, DRAW_NONE );
   SetIndexBuffer( 3, B4 );SetIndexStyle( 3, DRAW_NONE );
   return(0);
}
int start(){
      if (  T >= Bars ) T = Bars;

      SetIndexDrawBegin( 0, Bars - T + P + 1 );
      SetIndexDrawBegin( 1, Bars - T + P + 1 );
      SetIndexDrawBegin( 2, Bars - T + P + 1 );
      SetIndexDrawBegin( 3, Bars - T + P + 1 );

      int Z, C, Opt = IndicatorCounted();

      if (  Bars <= 38 ) return(0);

      if (  Opt  <  P ){
         for ( Z = 1; Z <= 0; Z++ ) G[T-Z] = 0.0;
         for ( Z = 1; Z <= 0; Z++ ) R[T-Z] = 0.0;
      }

      Z = T - P - 1;

      while( Z >= 0 ){
         double A, S1, S2;
         S1 = 0.0; for ( C = 0; C <= P - 1; C++ ){ S1 = S1 + (   High[Z+C] + Low[Z+C] ) / 2;}
         S2 = 0.0; for ( C = 0; C <= P - 1; C++ ){ S2 = S2 + ( ( High[Z+C] + Low[Z+C] ) * ( C+1 ) / 2 );}
         A  = S1 / S2;
         // if (  A < MIN ){ MIN = A;}
         // if (  A > MAX ){ MAX = A;}
         // A = ( MIN / MAX ) * 100;
         G[Z] = A;
         if (  Z > 0 ){ R[Z-1] = A;}
         Z--;
      }
      for ( int N = T-P-2; N >= 0; N-- ){
         if (  N > 0 ){
               if ( G[N-1] > G[N] ){ R[N] = EMPTY_VALUE; continue;}
               if ( G[N-1] < G[N] ){ G[N] = R[N];        continue;}
         }
         B3[0] = G[0] + P2;
         B4[0] = G[0] - P2; //forced quantise using 2 extra buffers
      }
      return(0);
   }
```

Comment: ? I have it compiled for meta trader 4, running it now! what are you using?

Comment: chris its called MetaEditor.exe and I think MT4 Has MQL as a language that is C++ with some differences/changes...

Comment: Oh, apart from the newly noticed `init` over `main`, nothing else stood out as different from C++. The tag is what confused me, then, as I was expecting C++ code inside.

Comment: I put both C++ and Mql as I was unsure how to ask this

Comment: Well, I didn't know of mql, so I was going off of the fact that it looked exactly like C++, unaware that mql was a language, so there was some ignorance on my part.

Comment: I think they boasted when they named it different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let´s split the task first

**0**) indicator **logic**
**1**) indicator **quantisation** step
**2**) indicator **performance**

**`MQL4`** Custom Indicator programming relies on deeper understanding of underlying <kbd>MetaTrader4 Terminal</kbd> platform. Each external Market Event, changing a traded instrument price, is signalled to a lcoalhost by a network delivery of a **`QUOTE ...`** message from <kbd>MetaTrader4 Server</kbd>. This is aka Tick and it triggers a call to a function originally called **`start()`**, in newer *New*-`MQL4.56789` renamed to **`OnTick()`**.

The below modified `MQL4` listing contains remarks for core-logic disambiguation, which must precede all the below listed steps.

---

### **1**) indicator **quantisation** step

While the code is still very inefficient ( as per [2] below ) the logic does not include any straight hurdle form having the output quantised to any form thereof { binary | ternary | arbitrary-number-of-states }-quantised system. Whence the indicator core-logic is cleared, the quantisation step is just a trivial conversion from **R(1)** to **I(1)**.

---

### **2**) indicator **performance**

Any Tick arrival **may, but need not** modify either `High[0]` or `Low[0]`, which are the only variable parts of the proposed Custom Indicator calculus.

This is the core idea on how to reduce the scope of re-calculations, that the `MQL4` code has to realise per tick. In recent versions of MT4, **all Custom Indicators share a single thread**, the more stress has been put on efficient algorithmisation of Custom Indicators, at these may block the platform's trading decisions on poor, inefficient code-loops and convolution/recursion re-executions.

```
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers   4
#property indicator_color1    Lime
#property indicator_color2    Red
#property indicator_color3    CLR_NONE
#property indicator_color4    CLR_NONE

extern int    P   =   13;
extern int    T   = 3000;
extern double P2  =    0.001;

double G[];                                                         // 0: LINE
double R[];                                                         // 1: LINE
double B3[];                                                        // 2: BUT NEVER PAINTED, NEVER CONSUMED _?_
double B4[];                                                        // 3: BUT NEVER PAINTED, NEVER CONSUMED _?_

int init(){
   IndicatorBuffers(4);
   SetIndexBuffer( 0, G  );SetIndexStyle( 0, DRAW_LINE, STYLE_SOLID, 1, Lime );
   SetIndexBuffer( 1, R  );SetIndexStyle( 1, DRAW_LINE, STYLE_SOLID, 1, Red  );
   SetIndexBuffer( 2, B3 );SetIndexStyle( 2, DRAW_NONE );
   SetIndexBuffer( 3, B4 );SetIndexStyle( 3, DRAW_NONE );
   return(0);
}
int start(){

    if (  Bars <= 38 ) return(0);                                   // JIT/RET in case Bars < 39 --^ --^ --^ --^

    if (  T >= Bars ) T = Bars;                                     // (TRIM´d) T < Bars .OR. = Bars

    int aDrawBegins     = Bars - T + P + 1;                         // ( extern P = 13 ) + 1 + ( Bars - ( extern T = 3000 if T < Bars else Bars ) )
    //tIndexDrawBegin( 0, Bars - T + P + 1 );                       // PREF: ( reused 4x )
    SetIndexDrawBegin( 0, aDrawBegins );                            // Draw  14+ last candles -- PREF: why a per tick hard-coded SHIFTING / enforced re-draw?
    SetIndexDrawBegin( 1, aDrawBegins );                            // Draw  14+ last candles -- PREF: why a per tick hard-coded SHIFTING / enforced re-draw?
    SetIndexDrawBegin( 2, aDrawBegins );                            // Draw  14+ last candles -- PREF: why a per tick hard-coded SHIFTING / enforced re-draw?
    SetIndexDrawBegin( 3, aDrawBegins );                            // Draw  14+ last candles -- PREF: why a per tick hard-coded SHIFTING / enforced re-draw?

    double A, S1, S2;                                               // auxiliary var for bar-mid-price calculi
    int    Z;                                                       // auxiliary stepper
    int    Opt = IndicatorCounted();                                // Opt ( NEVER RE-USED )

    if (  Opt  <  P ){                                              // if ( ( extern P = 13 ) > IndicatorCounted() )
       // ----------------------- ??? ----------------------------------------------------- NEVER EXEC´d: for( Z = 1++ v/s Z <= 0 )
       for ( Z = 1; Z <= 0; Z++ ) G[T-Z] = 0.0;                     // .STO G[T-Z], 0., BUT NEVER EXEC´d: for( Z = 1++ v/s Z <= 0 )
       for ( Z = 1; Z <= 0; Z++ ) R[T-Z] = 0.0;                     // .STO R[T-Z], 0., BUT NEVER EXEC´d: for( Z = 1++ v/s Z <= 0 )
       // ----------------------- ??? ----------------------------------------------------- NEVER EXEC´d: for( Z = 1++ v/s Z <= 0 )
    }

    Z = T - P - 1;                                                  // .STO Z, ( T = Bars (TRIM´d) ) - ( extern P = 13 ) - 1

    while( Z >= 0 ){                                                // .DEC Z
       //        !!! ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ // PERF: very inefficient to RE-calc STATIC ( ( extern P = 13 ) - 1 )-DEEP CONVOLUTIONS per tick !!
       S1 = 0.0; for ( int C = 0; C <= P - 1; C++ ){ S1 = S1 + (   High[Z+C] + Low[Z+C] )           / 2;  }
       S2 = 0.0; for ( int C = 0; C <= P - 1; C++ ){ S2 = S2 + ( ( High[Z+C] + Low[Z+C] ) * ( C+1 ) / 2 );}
       //        !!! ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ // PERF: very inefficient to RE-calc STATIC ( ( extern P = 13 ) - 1 )-DEEP CONVOLUTIONS per tick !!
       A  = S1 / S2;
       G[Z] = A;                                                    // .STO G[Z],   A if Z >= 0
       if (  Z > 0 ){ R[Z-1] = A;}                                  // .STO R[Z-1], A if Z >  0
       Z--;
    }

    for ( int N = T - P - 2; N >= 0; N-- ){                         // .STO N, ( T = Bars (TRIM´d) ) - ( extern P = 13 ) - 2
       if (   N > 0 ){                                              // N > 0:
              if ( G[N-1] > G[N] ){ R[N] = EMPTY_VALUE; continue;}  // .BLNK R[N], EMPTY if G[N-1] > G[N]
              if ( G[N-1] < G[N] ){ G[N] = R[N];        continue;}  // .SET  G[N], R[N]  if G[N-1] < G[N]
       }
    // ?? ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ // WHY MANY-TIMES RE-ASSIGNED A CONST. VALUE HERE, INSIDE A FOR(){...}-loop body? -------------- ??
       B3[0] = G[0] + P2;                                           // .STO B3[0], G[0] + ( extern P2 = 0.001 )
       B4[0] = G[0] - P2;                                           // .STO B4[0], G[0] - ( extern P2 = 0.001 )
                                                                    // forced quantise using 2 extra buffers
    // ?? ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ // WHY MANY-TIMES RE-ASSIGNED A CONST. VALUE HERE, INSIDE A FOR(){...}-loop body? -------------- ??
    }
    return(0);
}
```

---

### *New*-`MQL4.56789` syntax

The **`OnCalculate()`** function is called only in custom indicators when it's necessary to calculate the indicator values by the <kbd>Calculate event</kbd>. This usually happens when a new tick is received for the symbol, for which the indicator is calculated. This indicator is not required to be attached to any price chart of this symbol.

The first **`rates_total`** parameter contains the number of **`bars`**, available to the indicator for calculation, and corresponds to the number of bars available in the chart.

We should note the connection between the return value of **`OnCalculate()`** and the second input parameter **`prev_calculated`**. During the `OnCalculate()` function call, the `prev_calculated` parameter contains a value returned by `OnCalculate()` during **previous** call. This allows for economical algorithms for calculating the custom indicator in order to avoid repeated calculations for those bars that haven't changed since the previous run of this function.

For this, it is usually enough to return the value of the `rates_total` parameter, which contains the number of bars in the current function call. If since the last call of `OnCalculate()` the price data has changed (a deeper history downloaded or history blanks filled), the value of the input parameter `prev_calculated` **will be set to zero by the terminal.**

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
int  OnCalculate( const      int  rates_total,
                  const      int  prev_calculated,
                  const datetime &time[],
                  const   double &open[],
                  const   double &high[],
                  const   double &low[],
                  const   double &close[],
                  const     long &tick_volume[],
                  const     long &volume[],
                  const      int &spread[]
                  )
  {
  // Get the number of bars available now for the current Symbol and chart period 
     int barsNow = Bars( _Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT );

  // .RET value of prev_calculated for a next call
     return( rates_total );
  }
```